# Responsive Vertical scroll bar html document

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive

How to keep an HTML page full vertical scroll bar?? Permanantly fix horizontal scroll problem in responsive mode

I have already tried some of these suggestions:

1st way – 
`body { overflow-x:hidden; }`

2nd way –
"You can use the following in your CSS body tag:
`overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;`
That will remove your scrollbar."

3rd way –
`body { min-width: 1167px; }`

4th way –
`var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth; [].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('*'), function(el) { if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) { console.log(el); } } );`

5th way –
`html, body { max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; }`

6th way –
`element { max-width: 100vw; overflow-x: hidden; }`

Comment: Post your actual code along with what you tried so we can analyze what is going on.  Hard to say with just this information

Comment: Overflow properties - `auto` if you want scroll only when needed, `hidden` if you want no scrollbar at all, and `scroll` if you want scrollbar to always be there. Can't help with much else without some code example.

Comment: I have a problem with my main index.html  document....When i create div and add to some long text in paragraph tag..then chrome automatically add horizontal scroll bar..i want to make my site vertical scroll ....